# How to ignore whitespace in Kaleidoscope (diff tool)?

Tags: mac, diff

In [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/), how do I configure it to ignore whitespaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I emailed the support team and the answer is:

As of Kaleidoscope 1.1.2, there is no way to ignore whitespace in Kaleidoscope.

Also see this [tweet](https://twitter.com/#!/kaleidoscopeapp/status/50565459220762625)

Comment: 2.0.2 build 116 and still this option is missing.

Comment: This option is [finally being implemented](http://blackpixel.com/blog/2013/11/celebration-and-thanksgiving.html)!

Comment: clicked through your link Tachyon did not see anything mentioning the new option?

Comment: 4th paragraph: "and are in the process of shipping a new beta of Kaleidoscope with support for ignoring whitespace."

Answer (score 3):

Kaleidoscope 2.1 beta has the "ignore whitespace" feature. It is on the bottom toolbar. 
See: http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/beta

Comment: It's also a setting (Preferences ->Text->Ignore differences in whitespace)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/ for a free alternative that runs on OS X and supports many more functions than Kaleidoscope.

KDiff3 obviously doesn't have as fancy of an interface, but it works well and supports all the things Kaleidoscope is still lacking, like merging and whitespace/line ending ignoring.